# A Beginner Working on a Real Task with Python and EXIF

Tags: python, metadata, exif

Please go easy on me. It is about 3 decades since I coded anything ans I knew nothing about python until yesterday.

I have a a problem that I have been working on. I've gone through various iterations of the code and I stall at the same point. Reading the exif data from one file of a group of files and writing that to the other three files in the group.

**More About the Problem**

I have a drone for agricultural work. It has a Seqouia multispectral (MS) camera. The MS camera takes four images at one time and writes the files to onboard SD card.
The camera records these four images plus one RGB image. Sometimes the write rate affects the time stamp on usually one but sometimes two of the images in each group of four MS images. This affects the way that the "structure from motion" application processes the files. In fact it means that the app cannot do so. The app looks for Image DateTime stamp (EXIF 306) tag that matches. If there is no match, the app processing fails. I should point out that other paid services can process the images fine because they apparently use a different method.

**The code and structure of the files**

I first wrote a simple script to take the images from one path and separate the MS from RGB images, and place each in a sperate folder. Great, feeling successful!

I then played around with various ways of searching the new path for the MS images for tif files, reporting the number found (in this case 2472), this is a great validation when dealing with lots of files, then group those files in groups of four according to the first 23 characters of the file name.

NOTE: files generated by the MS camera are always consistently named according to this convention below

IMG_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS_INTE_BND.TIF

Where YYYY is year
MM is month
DD is date
INTEG is an integer of four digits
BND is BAND in three characters

Bands are GRE, RED, REG and NIR

Example: IMG_230406_233811_0001_GRE.TIF

So I wrote various iterations of scripts that searched for, found and correctly reported the number of files and also correctly grouped the files (by file name prefix) and reported the correct number of groups. They also reported on groups that had less than four files, due to the camera failing to write some images in that group of four. This apparently can happen when shooting rate is too high for the altitude and image overlap parameters.

The details of the groups of four files were placed in  a dictionary and also written to a .csv file in the output path.

A snippet of the .csv file is below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLIWp.png)

So the area of difficulty I am running in to is this

I want to iterate over each of these groups of four (there are 618 groups) and do a number of things

1. check for four files if not, skip that group and report skipped group (I had this working)
2. check that the four file names (path names) contain the four bands. It seems these are recorded as truncated labels in the dictionary RED = ED, GRE = RE, NIR = IR an REG = EG. this would seem the best to use but I could not get it tot work by searching for these. I also could not get the code to successfully find BND name in the path (tif_path) in the dictionary.
3. Read the exif 306 tag in the GRE file and write it to the other three files in that group of four.

The reason for writing the from the GRE file to the others is that the GRE file eg. IMG_230406_233811_0001_GRE.TIF is the first to write to SD and has the correct timestamp
All we need to do is ensure the other three MS files match

The problems I am having are in this interation

Many versions of the code I have written, falsely report missing bands.

Or cannot find the exif tag either by searching for DateTime Image_DateTime or exif306

I have been able to read all of the tags i earlier versions of my script and write them to console, so I know the tag is called Image DateTime

One version of code which correctly identified file numbers and groups but falsley reported missing bands is below

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List, Dict
from PIL import Image


def read_datetime_from_file(file_path: str) -> datetime:
    with Image.open(file_path) as im:
        exif = im._getexif()
        date_str = exif.get(36867)
        return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S')


def write_datetime_to_files(file_paths: List[str], datetime_obj: datetime, datetime_tag: str = 'EXIF DateTimeOriginal'):
    for file_path in file_paths:
        with open(file_path, 'rb+') as file:
            tags = exifread.process_file(file, details=False)
            tags[datetime_tag] = datetime_obj.strftime('%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S')
            file.seek(0)
            for tag, value in tags.items():
                if tag.startswith(datetime_tag):
                    continue
                file.write(f'{tag}: {value}\n'.encode('utf-8'))
            file.truncate()


def main():
    input_folder = Path(input("Enter the path to the input folder containing TIF files: "))
    output_folder = Path(input("Enter the path to the output folder: "))

    print(f"Searching for files with extensions ['.TIF'] in {input_folder}...")
    tif_paths = list(input_folder.glob('*.TIF'))
    print(f"Found {len(tif_paths)} TIF files in {input_folder}")

    # Group files by prefix (assumes prefix is the same for all files in the group)
    tif_groups = {}
    for path in tif_paths:
        tif_prefix = path.name[:23]
        if tif_prefix not in tif_groups:
            tif_groups[tif_prefix] = {'RE': None, 'IR': None, 'ED': None, 'EG': None}
        for band in ['RE', 'IR', 'ED', 'EG']:
            if band in path.name:
                tif_groups[tif_prefix][band] = path

    print(f"Grouping {len(tif_paths)} TIF files...")
    tif_groups = {k: v for k, v in tif_groups.items() if None not in v.values()}
    print(f"Grouped into {len(tif_groups)} groups.")

    # Loop over the TIF groups
    for tif_prefix, tif_paths in tif_groups.items():
        if len(tif_paths) != 4:
            print(f"Skipping group {tif_prefix}: incomplete group of TIF files")
            continue
        bands = [path.name[23:26] for path in tif_paths.values()]
        missing_bands = set(['GRE', 'RED', 'REG', 'NIR']) - set(bands)
        if missing_bands:
            print(f"Skipping group {tif_prefix}: missing bands {', '.join(missing_bands)}")
            continue

        # Read DateTime value from GRE file
        gre_datetime = read_datetime_from_file(tif_paths['GRE'])

        # Write DateTime value to other files in group
        for band in ['RED', 'REG', 'NIR']:
            write_datetime_to_files([tif_paths[band]], gre_datetime)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The first few lines of the output are here

Enter the path to the input folder containing TIF files: D:/Original
Enter the path to the output folder: D:Corrected
Searching for files with extensions ['.TIF'] in D:\Original...
Found 2472 TIF files in D:\Original
Grouping 2472 TIF files...
Grouped into 618 groups.
Skipping group IMG_230406_233809_0000_: missing bands GRE
Skipping group IMG_230406_233811_0001_: missing bands GRE
Skipping group IMG_230406_233813_0002_: missing bands GRE
Skipping group IMG_230406_233816_0003_: missing bands GRE
Skipping group IMG_230406_233818_0004_: missing bands GRE

I have tried in later scripts to read the tag like this

```
def main ()
# Loop over the TIF groups
    for tif_prefix, tif_paths in tif_groups.items():
        expected_labels = ['RE', 'ED', 'EG', 'IR']
        found_labels = []
        for label in expected_labels:
            for path in tif_paths.values():
                if str(path.name).startswith(label):
                    found_labels.append(label)
                    break
        if sorted(found_labels) != expected_labels:
            missing_labels = set(expected_labels) - set(found_labels)
            print(f"Skipping group {tif_prefix}: missing labels {', '.join(missing_labels)}")
            continue
```

and looking for exif 306

```
def read_datetime_from_file(file_path: str) -> datetime:
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
        tags = Image.open(file)._getexif()
        date_str = tags.get(306)
        if date_str is None:
            raise ValueError("Could not find datetime in EXIF tags")
        return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S')


def write_datetime_to_files(file_paths: List[str], datetime_obj: datetime):
    for file_path in file_paths:
        with open(file_path, 'rb+') as file:
            tags = Image.open(file)._getexif()
            tags[306] = datetime_obj.strftime('%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S')
            file.seek(0)
            for tag, value in tags.items():
                file.write(f'{tag}: {value}\n'.encode('utf-8'))
            file.truncate()
```

I'm sure in these early days I am committing all kinds of coding sins but I'm learning

Any help would be welcome.

The input files are here if you ant to play https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/wa90ql8i9vx234zy6x0fn/h?dl=0&rlkey=51t13ng8kxqcz10v1bewwxt0w

I have tried various versions of the scripts but I seem to fail with false reports of missing bands, and not being able to read the tag or find the tag or the file associated with the tag.

My specific questions are can any one assist me to determine the approach I should use (with code example) to 1. Correctly identify the four bands when iterating 2. find and read the exif tag in the GRE file 3. write the value of this tag to the other three files in each group of four?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour], [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [ask]. Also see [mre]

Comment: You have written a lot of text and shown much detail of your code, but it's not very clear what your specific question is.

Comment: My specific questions are 

can any one assist me to determine the approach I should use (with code example) to

1. Correctly identify the four bands when iterating
2. find and read the exif tag in the GRE file 
3. write the value of this tag to the other three files in each group of four

Comment: Please try to limit your posts to a single question, rather than ask about your whole approach beginning to end. Create multiple posts for each part, if you have to. Refer links in the first comment. For example, if someone searched "EXIF with Python", they would find this post, but probably has nothing to with with _their problem_. If you asked "how to loop over files / image sections of length four", you might get more direct results.

Comment: Alright but the post is done now and it's not difficult for people to answers in the same manner as I have asked- with numbered list. Additionally asking multiple questions gives context

Comment: This explanation fits your post quite well: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: I have very specific questions

My specific questions are can any one assist me to determine the approach I should use (with code example) to 1. Correctly identify the four bands when iterating 2. find and read the exif tag in the GRE file 3. write the value of this tag to the other three files in each group of four?

If you prefer,  I'll rephrase it

How, given the objectives explained, and the code shown do I 1. Correctly identify the four bands when iterating 2. find and read the exif tag in the GRE file 3. write the value of this tag to the other three files in each group of four?

Comment: "_enter image description here_" does not exist for fun - replace it with meaningful text. Also writing [Real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RealNetworks) in uppercase (and at all) might imply that vendor/software - consider using non-header = normal casing in text.

Answer (score 0):

When processing EXIF data, I would be inclined to let `exiftool` do most of the heavy lifting - it can output JSON or CSV - depending on what you are more comfortable with. Either run this first, or use `subprocess.run()`:

```
exiftool -csv -datetimeoriginal *.TIF > images.csv
```

That gives you a file like this:

```
SourceFile,DateTimeOriginal
IMG_230406_233811_0001_NIR.TIF,2023:04:06 23:38:11
IMG_230406_233811_0001_RED.TIF,2023:04:06 23:38:11
IMG_230406_233811_0001_REG.TIF,2023:04:06 23:38:11
IMG_230406_233816_0003_GRE.TIF,2023:04:06 23:38:16
IMG_230406_233816_0003_NIR.TIF,2023:04:06 23:38:16
...
...
```

Then process in a similar fashion to this:

```
import csv

# Build list of all images
images = []
with open('images.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for dictionary in reader:
        images.append(dictionary)
```

That gives a list of dicts like this:

```
[{'SourceFile': 'IMG_230406_233811_0001_NIR.TIF',
  'DateTimeOriginal': '2023:04:06 23:38:11'},
 {'SourceFile': 'IMG_230406_233811_0001_RED.TIF',
  'DateTimeOriginal': '2023:04:06 23:38:11'},
 {'SourceFile': 'IMG_230406_233811_0001_REG.TIF',
  'DateTimeOriginal': '2023:04:06 23:38:11'},
...
...
```

And you can get a set of the unique INTEGERs in your filenames like this:

```
# Get set of INTEGERs
ints = {x['SourceFile'][18:22] for x in images}
```

giving this:

```
{'0001',
 '0003',
 '0007',
 '0008',
 ...
 ...
 '0404',
 '0406',
 '0415'}
```

Comment: Thanks for that it's helpful for getting the tags.

I have to first or at some time group the images into groups of four. I guess I could do that after the dictionary above is created. The reason I have to group them is to take datetime from one file and apply it to others in the group of four

Comment: Sorry, I understood you had to group them by the INTEGER, rather than in fours, that's why I extracted the INTEGER.

Comment: You are not wrong. The integer is the same for each of the four images. The difference comes after the integer. The difference is the next three characters after the next underscore, the band. So IMG_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS_INTE_BAND.TIF